# insert batch from array 2 dimension codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I wanto insert and insert batch from one form to 2 tables and post data have contain array 2 dimension, and the result from **print_r** post data

```
Array
(
[foo] => blalala
[bar] => xxxxxx
[date] => 2014-06-30
[time] => 08:34:30
[fruit] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 4
    )

[car] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 5
        [3] => 7
    )

[food] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 3
    )

[drink] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
    )

[snack] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
    )

)
```

and the result i want

```
$array_master = array(
   [foo] => blalala,
   [bar] => xxxxxx,
   [date] => 2014-06-30,
   [time] => 08:34:30,
);
```

and the next array count data from 2nd dimension array [fruit],[food],[car],[drink],[snack]

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [agenda_terkait_type] => **(if [fruit] ==1,[food] ==2,[car] ==3,[drink] ==4,[snack] ==5)**
            [agenda_terkait_agenda_id] => 
            [agenda_terkait_data_id] => (value of [fruit],[food],[car],[drink],[snack])
            [agenda_terkait_status] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [agenda_terkait_type] => 
            [agenda_terkait_agenda_id] => 121
            [agenda_terkait_data_id] => 
            [agenda_terkait_status] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [agenda_terkait_type] => 
            [agenda_terkait_agenda_id] => 121
            [agenda_terkait_data_id] => 
            [agenda_terkait_status] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [agenda_terkait_type] => 
            [agenda_terkait_agenda_id] => 121
            [agenda_terkait_data_id] => 
            [agenda_terkait_status] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [agenda_terkait_type] => 
            [agenda_terkait_agenda_id] => 121
            [agenda_terkait_data_id] => 
            [agenda_terkait_status] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [agenda_terkait_type] => 
            [agenda_terkait_agenda_id] => 121
            [agenda_terkait_data_id] => 
            [agenda_terkait_status] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [agenda_terkait_type] => 
            [agenda_terkait_agenda_id] => 121
            [agenda_terkait_data_id] => 
            [agenda_terkait_status] => 1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [agenda_terkait_type] => 
            [agenda_terkait_agenda_id] => 121
            [agenda_terkait_data_id] => 
            [agenda_terkait_status] => 1
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [agenda_terkait_type] => 1
            [agenda_terkait_agenda_id] => 121
            [agenda_terkait_data_id] => 
            [agenda_terkait_status] => 1
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [agenda_terkait_type] => 1
            [agenda_terkait_agenda_id] => 121
            [agenda_terkait_data_id] => 
            [agenda_terkait_status] => 1
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [agenda_terkait_type] => 2
            [agenda_terkait_agenda_id] => 121
            [agenda_terkait_data_id] => 
            [agenda_terkait_status] => 1
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [agenda_terkait_type] => 2
            [agenda_terkait_agenda_id] => 121
            [agenda_terkait_data_id] => 
            [agenda_terkait_status] => 1
        )
```

Thank's for help. I'll appreciate. and sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use foreach loops to get this: Try this:

```
$original_values = array(
    'foo' => 'blalala',
    'bar' => 'xxxxxx',
    'date' => '2014-06-30',
    'time' => '08:34:30',
    'fruit' => array(1, 2, 3, 4),
    'car' => array(2, 3, 5, 7),
    'food' => array(2, 3),
    'drink' => array(3),
    'snack' => array(2),
);


$array_master = array();
foreach ($original_values as $key => $value) {
    if(!is_array($value)) {
        $array_master[$key] = $value;
        unset($original_values[$key]);
    }
}

$batch = array();
foreach($original_values as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $element) {
        $type = '';
        switch($key) {
            case 'fruit':
                $type = 1;
            break;
            case 'car':
                $type = 2;
            break;
            case 'food':
                $type = 3;
            break;
            case 'drink':
                $type = 4;
            break;
            case 'snack':
                $type = 5;
            break;
        }
        $batch[] = array(
            'agenda_terkait_type' => $type,
            'agenda_terkait_agenda_id' => '',
            'agenda_terkait_data_id' => $element,
            'agenda_terkait_status' => 1,
        );
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array_master);
print_r($batch);
```

It outputs like this:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => blalala
    [bar] => xxxxxx
    [date] => 2014-06-30
    [time] => 08:34:30
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [agenda_terkait_type] => 1
            [agenda_terkait_agenda_id] => 
            [agenda_terkait_data_id] => 1
            [agenda_terkait_status] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [agenda_terkait_type] => 1
            [agenda_terkait_agenda_id] => 
            [agenda_terkait_data_id] => 2
            [agenda_terkait_status] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [agenda_terkait_type] => 1
            [agenda_terkait_agenda_id] => 
            [agenda_terkait_data_id] => 3
            [agenda_terkait_status] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [agenda_terkait_type] => 1
            [agenda_terkait_agenda_id] => 
            [agenda_terkait_data_id] => 4
            [agenda_terkait_status] => 1
        )
.. to be continued
```